# HTML Select Always have Blue Background Regardless of Focus

Tags: html, css, focus

I am using this example of HTML select multiple Attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple. The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The select multiple attribute</h1>

<p>The multiple attribute specifies that multiple options can be selected at once:</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Hold down the Ctrl (windows) or Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I select the Volvo option, it has a **blue** background:

[image]

When I click somewhere else on the screen (to remove the focus), the background for Volvo becomes **grey**:

[image]

**My question**: How do I make the background on my selection (in this case, Volvo) always blue, regardless of focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the `color` and `background-color` cannot be changed with the  `:checked` pseudo-element, but it can be mimic with the help of a `linear-gradient`.

```css
option:checked {
  background: linear-gradient(lightblue, lightblue);
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is use a linear gradient.

```css
select option:checked{
  background: #1E90FF -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #1E90FF 0%, #1E90FF 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```